# Insert result into temp table mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

i am trying to insert my results to a temporary table i created before.
Dont know why this is not working. Need help thank you.
Code:

```
SET @serial = '75900101';
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS machinenametable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE machinenametable (id INT, name VARCHAR(100));

WITH machine_data AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    machine m
WHERE 
    @serial = m.serial
), machine_id AS (
SELECT
    1 AS id,
    (IF(
        md.identifier LIKE 'PP%',
        (SELECT 'PP'),
        IF(
            md.identifier LIKE 'SHL',
            (SELECT 'SHL'),
            (SELECT 'SL')
        )
    ))  AS machine
FROM machine_data md
)
INSERT INTO machinenametable (id, name)
SELECT id, name FROM machine_id
```

Something with this Insert into is wrong but i dont have any idea why....
Getting a Error Msg :

```
SQL-Error[1064] [42000]: (conn=3127818) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO machinenametable (id, name)
```

EDIT:
This is Working:

```
INSERT INTO machinenametable (id, name)
    SELECT
        1 AS id,
            (CASE WHEN m.identifier LIKE 'PP%' THEN 'PP'
             WHEN m.identifier LIKE 'SHL' THEN 'SHL'
             ELSE 'SL'
             END) AS name
    FROM machine m
    WHERE @serial = m.serial
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  If so please include that in the question.  Unexpected data?  Then you need to tell us about some example input, show us the incorrect output you are getting and what you expected.

Comment: You could use a case expression instead of all those if() statements.

Comment: Yes i know its not about the IF. Only my insert into isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very complicated logic for something that seems rather simple.  I think this does what you want:

```
INSERT INTO machinenametable (id, name)
    SELECT 1,
           (CASE WHEN md.identifier LIKE 'PP%' THEN 'PP'
                 WHEN md.identifier LIKE 'SHL' THEN 'SHL'
                 ELSE 'SL'
            END)
    FROM machine m
    WHERE  @serial = m.serial;
```

The CTE do nothing useful.  And the use of `IF` instead of `CASE` is convoluted.  And using `SELECT` for constants is simply unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the usage of the insert command.

Edit the INSERT command and use as

`INSERT INTO machinenametable VALUES(id, name)`

Comment: I tried everything and this too. The normal way to insert something is working like `INSERT INTO machinenametable (id, name) VALUES(1, 'asdf');` but this not